# adding a boolean modifier to a rig/bone character

Tags: animation, modifiers

so I was doing animation and wanted to add boolean to a character but I can't find the modifier tab is there any way I could add a boolean modifier? I've searched the web but couldn't find anything all I know is that it has to be a mesh but I don't know to change a bone/rig to a mesh while still keeping the animation

Comment: of course you can use a boolean to change the mesh, you'll just have to weight paint the additional vertices so that it knows what bone is supposed to influence them

Answer (score 0):

The armature is a separate object. If you look in the outliner, you will most likely find the character mesh object parented to the armature. You should be able to add a boolean modifier to that object.